# Referencing External Workbook VBA through Variable and If Statement

Tags: vba, excel

Currently my code looks like this and it works fine

```
    Dim WorkbookVar As Workbook
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "C:\Path.xlsx"
    Set WorkbookVariable = Workbooks.Open (Filename:=MCDistroNumberPath)
```

But I would like it to go a step further and have an if statement saying `If` this workbook is already open `Then` skip it and start running the rest of my macro.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I found this example, but cannot seem to bridge the two together. http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/IsWorkbookOpen.htm

Comment: `for each b in application.workbooks | if not b.fullname= MCDistroNumberPath then` Not sure why your variable name changed...

Comment: And the file name is disconnected from the path in the example, but never-the-less, @findwindow has a good solution, I tend to do something like the following:`On Error Resume Next: Set WorkbookVariable = Workbooks(Filename:=MCDistroNumberPath): On Error GoTo 0
    If Not WorkbookVariable Is Nothing Then Set WorkbookVariable = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MCDistroNumberPath)`

Answer (score 3):

Consider putting it into its own function like below.

```
Public Function GetOrOpenWorkbook(ByVal sFullPath As String) As Workbook

    Dim wbReturn As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wbReturn = Workbooks(Dir(sFullPath))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wbReturn Is Nothing Then
        Set wbReturn = Workbooks.Open(sFullPath)
    End If

    Set GetOrOpenWorkbook = wbReturn

End Function

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = GetOrOpenWorkbook("C:\Path\Path.xlsx")

End Sub
```

The `Dir` function will return just the file name without the path. If a workbook with that name is already open, it will return that workbook. If not, it attempts to open it.

Comment: Nice. But we could get the name from the path using string manipulation, without "disturbing" the OS ;)